# What exactly does "not enough eligible nominations" mean in a moderator election?

Tags: support, election

[Music.SE is having an election](https://music.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) where currently there is only 1 candidate for the 1 position.  The explanation for the Nomination Phase says:

> If there are **not enough eligible nominations** at the end of the nomination period, it will be extended by one week. If there are not enough nominations after an extension the election will be canceled.

What does "not enough" mean?

1. If the number of candidates equal the number of positions, is that "enough"?
2. If the nomination phase ends like this, will it be extended or will it go straight to the election phase?
3. As it currently stands (# of candidates = # of positions), is the election at risk to be cancelled?

Comment: It's a full election, so this passage from the FAQ applies: "If there are too few nominees, depending on whether the election is declared as a full election or a pro tem election, the following will happen: --- In full elections, if the number of nominees is less than or equal to the number of moderator slots, the nomination period will be extended by seven days, and if there are still not enough nominees to make the election competitive, the election will be cancelled entirely."

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks.  I didn't realize there is a general SE [Community FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) which is much more detailed than the Help Center.  Will consult it first next time.